# Javascript way to locate all elements with margin: auto

Tags: javascript, css, margin

I'm looking for an easy way to locate elements on the page that have margin-left and margin-right set to auto.

I got this script, that helps me some of the time:

```js
(function() {
  var elementsList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    if (styleSheet.rules) {
      for (var j = 0; j < styleSheet.rules.length; j++) {
        var rule = styleSheet.rules[j];
        if (rule && rule.style && rule.style.marginLeft == 'auto' && rule.style.marginRight == 'auto') {
          var smallList = document.querySelectorAll(rule.selectorText);
          if (smallList.length)
            elementsList = elementsList.concat(smallList);

        }

      }
    }
  }
  return elementsList
})();
```

While this function gets some of the job done, it doesn't catch most cases of `margin: auto` I've seen in websites.

Can you show me a better way?

Comment: There is an easier way. Why do not you create a class? Something like .margin-auto and search by all these elements?

Comment: This sounds like a jQuery selector problem.  Do you want that?

Comment: You will have it a lot easyer if you include jquery and simply use the selectors there. @MDeSchaepmeester TO BITE YOU ;)

Comment: I think you should better go with `getComputedStyles` to reliably filter elements with `margin-left/right` equal to `auto`. Also `document.styleSheets` is smart but there is also a possibility of inline styles. That being said, the code is going to be pretty greedy as you need to scan many page elements. You can make it a little bit more efficient by skipping inline elements and elements like `<br>`.

Comment: @dfsq Unfortunately this fails in FF and Safari, both returns `0px` when margins are set to `auto` even when they render correctly centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you're OK to use JQuery**

As said by Martin Ernst for yonatan's answer: 'This will select only elements with marginLeft/Right="auto".'

Besides, as described in the comments, elements must be hidden in order to work with FF and safari.

This should work using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visibleElements = $('body *:visible');
    $('body *').hide();
    var elements = $('body *').filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('margin-left') == 'auto' && $(this).css('margin-right') == 'auto';
    })
    // show only elements that were visible
    visibleElements.show();
});
```

***Tip***: if for some reason, you need to not load external scripts, just copy the content of the minified jquery script at the begining of yours.

Comment: Unfortunately this fails in FF and Safari, both returns `0px` when margins are set to `auto` even when they render correctly centered.

Comment: Can you do all actions you want on the dom? If you can, call $('*').hide();  at the very beginning of your script. Doing this, the 'auto' value won't be calculated (well, I think so... ;) ). If it works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Correct, but hide() should undo those calculations (I've ever done this kind of 'brachial' things ^^).

Comment: If I type this following code in the console, with this stackoverflow page displayed, I get elements with chrome and FF, don't you?     $('*').hide();$('body *').filter(function() { return $(this).css('margin-left') == 'auto' && $(this).css('margin-right') == 'auto'; })

Comment: Yeah it works, I did it in the wrong script. Include it (in `($(document).ready` and a `show()` afterwards), and I will upvote.

Comment: Done. I suggest showing only the elements that were visible.

Comment: Now it works for FF too! But, sad to say, Safari fails totally and IE sometimes miss half of the elements.

Comment: This solution is crazy - I have to try it!!

Comment: Nicolas - this is genius. This is exactly what I looked for (I had to drop jQuery, but it works great!!!)

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery:
`$('*').filter(function(i, d){return d.style.marginLeft == "auto" && d.style.marginRight == 'auto';});`

Comment: He'd better use $('body *'), this avoid looping into unecessary elements (head, meta, etc.).

Comment: This will select only elements with `marginLeft/Right="auto"` set in their `style-attribute`, but not those where it's set by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, but this one has less success then my own version.

Comment: Your problem is **not trivial**. Did you try **Nicolas** answer ? It should work except in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is **not trivial**. Even in the days of `window.getComputedStyle()` it's hard to get a crossbrowser reliable answer for marginLeft/Right when margins are set to `auto`. So this is shurely not a complete answer but will try helping to find one.

`margin-left` and `margin-right` are also `auto` when the margin-shorthand is used:

```
#elem {margin: auto;} // or:
#elem {margin: 100px auto;} // or:
#elem {margin: 100px auto 30px;} // or:
#elem {margin: 100px auto 30px auto;}
```

You have to find those notations too when you are searching in the stylesheets. Include this function just before `var elementsList=[];` in your code:

```
function expand(margin) {
    var parts = margin.split(' ');
    for (var i = 3; i; i--) parts[i] = parts[i] || parts[i - 2] || parts[0];
    return parts[1] == 'auto' && parts[3] == 'auto';
}
```

Then change your inner `if-condition` to:

```
if (rule && rule.style &&
    (rule.style.marginLeft == 'auto' && rule.style.marginRight == 'auto' || expand(rule.style.margin))
) {
    var smallList = document.querySelectorAll(rule.selectorText);
    if (smallList.length) elementsList = elementsList.concat(smallList);
}
```

Now you get also the rules where `margin` is used. But some problems stay with your code:

- Same elements may be listed multiple times when they match more than one rule
- It's not shure that all listet elements are really rendered with marginLeft/Right = auto. Maybe that css becomes overridden by another more specific rule.
- As **dfsq** mentioned in his comment there can be inline-styles you can't find this way.

Comment: I acctually don't care much about cross-browser compatibility. I want to create an addon to any browser, that will detect the margin auto elements (and do stuff, you need to know about :))